# Xcode Obj C - back button gone on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I'm having a problem in xcode where I'm using a UISplitViewController. After opening the left pane/table view, selecting a row in the table View, and then closing the pane the back button disappears. I'm not sure when this  started happening, perhaps after updating to Xcode 7. I tried fixing it with code - changing, removing or adding code that would show the back button, nothing so far have worked. That being said, I don't think this is a problem that can be solved using code, this is a standard controller (the UISplitViewController that is) that's bundled with Xcode, and it should just work out of the box. Anyone heard of this problem before, or anyone who is aware of a fix?

Just to be clear, if I open and close the left pane only, the back button does not disappear, it will still be there. It only happens when I open the pane, select an item/row, and close it. The pane can still be pulled out/opened by swiping from the left side of the screen towards the center after the button is gone.

Here is a snippet of the navigation bar of the ipad simulator after the back button is gone:

[image: back button gone]

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I currently have changed the tableViewController to a viewController for MasterViewController.m (I started this project from the UISplitViewController template that's bundled with Xcode, which uses a tableViewController by default)

Comment: definetely it has something to do with the code. show us the code  related to present and dismiis the view controller.

Comment: There is no code for presenting or dismissing the viewcontroller as such, both the detail and tableview is loaded when launching the app. There is a prepareForSegue method that passes all the data to the detail, but this does not have any effects on the content of the navigation bar (i tried commenting out the entire prepareForSegue function)